# Input language ignored with external keyboard on ipadOS

Tags: keyboard, language, ipados

It is rather strange, but sometimes language switching in ipadOS with external keyboard ignores the selected language (see the image). Sometimes it works correctly (e.g. in spotlight search), but in many apps (I checked at least several) it's completely erratic. Sometimes it does get switched, sometimes it doesn't and the selected language is being completely ignored, despite the selected language icon.

It doesn't make any difference if I chose the language at the touchscreen or with keyboard shortcut (CTRL+Space). I tried to restart iPad, doesn't help.

Can anyone have any suggestions what tricks to try to fix this? I'm getting desperate losing the ability to use it over such a silly issue..

iPadOS 15.6.1

[image: Language switch fail]

Comment: What hardware keyboard are you using?  Can you rest with a different one?

Comment: @TomGewecke I'm using Apple Magic Keyboard. I also use it with my MacBook without any issue. Where do you think I can report this?

Comment: Try using caps lock to switch keyboards and see if any better.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks, tried that. Didn't help unfortunately. Interesting. I didn't realize that external keyboard + multi-language input would be such a niche use case that nobody reported it so far.

Comment: Most users affected are probably posting in Apple's forums rather than here.  In any case, the place to report is http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me, it helped to turn off “Full keyboard Access” in Settings.

In order to turn it off, Go to Settings > Accessibility > Keyboards > Full Keyboard Access > Turn off Full Keyboard Access.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Full Keyboard Access being turn on causes causes lots of other problems, but this is the first time I have heard of it affecting language switching. Very helpful to know.  Luckily I think very few users have it activated, except by mistake.

Comment: Confirming, it "solved" the issue! Obviously it's only a workaround, the real issue must be solved by Apple.